# Sprite Kit iOS 7.1 crash on wasRemovedFromTargetAtTime

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I have a crash in Sprite Kit on iOS 7.1. I tried to build with Xcode 5.0.2 and 5.1. Results are the same. Still crashing on iOS 7.1 devices.

Here are attached screenshots.

[image]
[image]

I found the code which generated the crash.

```
- (WATDirection *)panDown {
WATDirection *direction = [[WATDirection alloc] init];

CGFloat newY = 830;

@weakify(self)
[direction addStartHandler:^(WATDirection *direction) {
    @strongify(self)

    self.panningDown = YES;

    [self runAction:[self animateNextArrowFadeOut] withKey:@"next_arrow"];

    // Move the scene
    SKAction *panDown = [SKAction moveToY:newY duration:1.5];
    panDown.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseInEaseOut;

    [self.rootNode runAction:panDown withKey:@"panDown"];

    // Fade in the pipes
    SKNode *pipes = [self.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"pipes"];

    SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction waitForDuration:0.3],
        [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:0.6]
    ]];

    [pipes runAction:fadeIn withKey:@"fadeIn"];

    [pipes enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"pipe" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        SKAction *fadeIn = [SKAction sequence:@[
            [SKAction waitForDuration:1.1],
            [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:0.6],
        ]];

        [node runAction:fadeIn withKey:@"fadeIn"];
    }];

    // Fade out the overlay
    SKNode *pipesOverlay = [pipes childNodeWithName:@"pipes_overlay"];

    SKAction *fadeOut = [SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction waitForDuration:3.0],
        [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0 duration:0.5],
        [SKAction removeFromParent]
    ]];

    [pipesOverlay runAction:fadeOut withKey:@"fadeOut"];

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction waitForDuration:3.5],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            [direction finish];
        }]
    ]]];
}];

[direction addFinishHandler:^(WATDirection *direction) {
    @strongify(self)

    [self runAction:[self animateNextArrowFadeIn] withKey:@"next_arrow"];

    self.panningDown = NO;
    self.pannedDown = YES;
}];

[direction addCancelHandler:^(WATDirection *direction) {
    @strongify(self)

    SKAction *panDown = [SKAction moveToY:newY duration:0];

    [self.rootNode runAction:panDown withKey:@"panDown"];

    SKNode *pipesOverlay = [self childNodeWithName:@"//pipes_overlay"];
    [pipesOverlay removeFromParent];

    [self runAction:[self animateNextArrowFadeIn] withKey:@"next_arrow"];

    self.panningDown = NO;
    self.pannedDown = YES;
}];

return direction;
```

}

These 2 lines are the problem:

```
@strongify(self)

    [self runAction:[self animateNextArrowFadeIn] withKey:@"next_arrow"];
```

Any ideas over this?

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: please set an exception breakpoint, do some investigation related to the source near the crash, then post some code.

Comment: @Ilario this is the problem. I can't find the code that generates this error.

Comment: @danh I did that. No success. With Zombies enabled generates the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. There were 2 actions with the same animationKey @"next_arrow".

```
[self runAction:[self animateNextArrowFadeIn] withKey:@"next_arrow"];
```

Second actions starts before first action finishes. Second action tries to remove animation with that key from the queue but there was no action with that key because first action removed that from the queue.

The fix is to rename the action key for the second animation.

```
[self runAction:[self animateNextArrowFadeIn] withKey:@"next_arrow_down"];
```

Thanks all for your support!

Comment: I can understand that this would work, but one of the main purposes of those keys is to allow runAction:withKey: to automatically remove a pre-existing action with the same key.  This is something we __want__ to be able to do.

Comment: maybe it has a different behaviour now. I did't have a chance to work with SpriteKit anymore.

Comment: It's quite possible that it's another bug in the SpriteKit API.  I'm still seeing problems in this area, even when dealing with one action that is supposed to be replaced by another, and have built a workaround for it.